# How do I download files to certain path and execute the downloaded file via batch?

Tags: batch-file, save, filepath

Sorry for the bad title but I'm really desperate for help!

I am currently trying to figure out how to download files via a batch file script, save the downloaded file to a certain path and then execute the downloaded file from the path where I saved the downloaded file.

In theory I want it to work like this:

1. I open the batch file script
2. It starts to download a file from this direct link : https://example.com/download/file.vbs
3. It saves the downloaded file to \AppData\Local\Temp
4. It executes the downloaded file thats now saved in \AppData\Local\Temp

At the moment I can execute the files from certain directories only if I enter my exact system path. The problem is, that I also want this to work on other peoples systems.

Again I am sorry for my bad explanation, I am all new to this.

Comment: Just to add, if you do not want to use the location an end user has chosen as an alternative `%TEMP%` or `%TMP%` value, _(as those are user configurable)_, you could based upon the output you should have seen when following the advice in the openeing sentence of the first comment, have noted that the modern Windows default location is `"%LOCALAPPDATA%\Temp"`, so you could use that instead. I will add however, that when most executable files are downloaded on a modern Windows PC, their direct use is protected by the built-in security. Your end user will probably have to accept a prompt message.

Answer (score 0):

the answer was easy

```
@echo off
powershell -c "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://example.com/download/file.vbs' -OutFile '%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\file.vbs'"
cd "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\"
start "file.vbs"
```